# use JAXB xml instead of reading property file in java

Tags: java, xml

I just want to know if we can use xml file instead of property file in big
application process to fetch values  directly into jsp file in java.

In Property file we can simply get value  like

```
"var name = "<bean:write name='name'/>";" Struts.
```

I have seen Java Architecture for XML Binding (JABX) will  convert Java
object to / from XML file.

Instead of passing property file I wanna to pass xml file .
Help me to do this in my Project

For loading a property file into java file we require this type of iteration.

```
java.util.Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("db.properties"));
```

I know the way how to store the key pair values into xml from java
using
JAXB Marshalling..
But the values fetch from xml into java we can use Unmarshalling...

suppose the property file like named

```
please.enter.franchisor=Please enter the name of  Franchisor
```

this property key will be displayed using struts variable 
"bean:message"

```
<div><bean:message key="please.enter.franchisor"/></div>
```

The same thing I want to do instead of property into XML.
Cause less memory in operation and performance wealth.

It will be in XML file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>


<franchisor>Please enter the name of  Franchisor</franchisor>
```

and I want to use this into bean or any other way into front end instead
of property file

Comment: Its missed ...
<script> 
 var messsage= "<bean:message key='test.msg.key' />";

Comment: please provide a sample xml

Comment: I have used jab to serialize->send-deserialize over rest/web requests.I have never looked at the files themselves. Not sure if the file format will be easier than props

Comment: Thank guys for your valuable replies....